# How to seamlessly loop Video in Adobe Flash?

Tags: html, actionscript-3, flash, html5-video

I import the video to the stage (name it flvControl), set autoPlay to true and then I am trying the following code that is supposed to do the job, but it doesn't work.

```
function completeHandler(event:fl.video.VideoEvent):void
{
    flvControl.play();
}

flvControl.addEventListener(fl.video.VideoEvent.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
```

When you test movie in Flash, it has half a second white screen flicker in between playbacks, but when you test in a browser (mine is Chrome) not only there is a flicker in between, on subsequent playthroughs video seems to freeze for about 1-2 seconds and then starts to play from about 1-2 seconds down the video. Which essentially makes looping completely unplayable.

Does anyone know how to make video loop seamlessly in Flash? (And to look seamless in browser too?)

Comment: You could try using seek instead of play (as play probably tries to load the file again)  `flvControl.seek(0)`  The delay though may be in the event dispatching.  Typically when I do this I work with a net stream directly - the flvplayback component abstracts it all out.  Do you need to use the FLVPlayback component?

Comment: seek(0) doesnt help, I tried it before. I am good with any technology that can do it consistently across browsers. (even HTML5). How do you do it with Netstream? I found quite a few code examples on the internet, but they all had a flicker problem as well when I tried them

Comment: The HTML5 video node has a loop attribute I believe.  You shouldn't be using flash in a browser anymore unless it's a controlled environment anyway.

Comment: In my case I need to loop a video specific number of times. Not even mentioning the fact that seamless looping with HTML5 is not fully supported on all browsers. The reason I turned to flash is exactly because HTML5 didnt work for me. Imagine my annoyance when I realized exactly the same thing doesnt work in Flash as well!

Comment: I've seen it work in both Flash & the HTML5 Video tag.  The loop attribute has good browser support but you'd still have to use some JS to make it stop after x loops.  Where is your video comming from? Local file, media server?  How that file is served/cached is likely the difference maker

Comment: Nothing I tried worked perfectly. At most only in some particular cases. If you can provide the code that works that would be great. My video is coming from local file but I can change it to anything else if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I've found to seamlessly loop video is to load the entire clip into memory ByteArray and then use the appendBytes function of a NetStream connected to a Video instance.

Here is a very basic helper class

```
package 
{
    import flash.events.AsyncErrorEvent;
    import flash.events.NetStatusEvent;
    import flash.events.SecurityErrorEvent;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.media.Video;
    import flash.net.NetConnection;
    import flash.net.NetStream;
    import flash.net.NetStreamAppendBytesAction;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.utils.setTimeout;


    /** 
    * @author   Michael Archbold (ma&#64;distriqt.com)
    */
    public class AppendByteVideoLoop
    {
        public function AppendByteVideoLoop(video:Video, data:ByteArray):void
        {
            _video = video;
            connect(data);
        }

        private var _video:Video;
        private var _connection:NetConnection;
        private var _stream:NetStream;
        private var _byteArray:ByteArray;
        private var _timer:Timer;

        private var _paused : Boolean = false;
        public function get paused():Boolean { return _paused; }


        public function play():void
        {
            if (_stream)
                _stream.resume();
        }


        public function pause():void
        {
            if (_stream)
                _stream.pause();
        }


        public function togglePause():void
        {
            if (_stream)
                _stream.togglePause();
        }


        private function connect(byteArray:ByteArray):void
        {
            _byteArray = byteArray;

            _connection = new NetConnection();
            _connection.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler);
            _connection.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandler);
            _connection.connect(null);
        }


        private function addToStream():void
        {
            _stream.appendBytesAction(NetStreamAppendBytesAction.RESET_BEGIN);
            _stream.appendBytes(_byteArray);
        }


        public function onMetaData(metaData:Object):void
        {
//          _video.width  = metaData.width;
//          _video.height = metaData.height;
        }


        public function onXMPData(xmp:Object):void
        {
        }


        public function onPlayStatus(status:Object):void
        {
        }


        private function connectStream():void
        {
            _stream = new NetStream(_connection);
            _stream.client = this;
            _stream.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler);
            _stream.addEventListener(AsyncErrorEvent.ASYNC_ERROR, asyncErrorHandler);
            _video.attachNetStream(_stream);
            _stream.play(null);
            _stream.appendBytes(_byteArray);
            _stream.pause();
        }


        private function netStatusHandler(event:NetStatusEvent):void
        {
            trace(event.info.code);
            switch (event.info.code)
            {
                case "NetConnection.Connect.Success": 
                    connectStream();
                    break;

                case "NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound": 
                    trace( "Unable to locate video " );
                    break;

                case "NetStream.Pause.Notify":
                    _paused = true;
                    break;

                case "NetStream.Unpause.Notify":
                    _paused = false;
                    break;

                case "NetStream.Buffer.Empty":
                    addToStream();
                    break;

                case "NetStream.Buffer.Full":
                    break;

            }
        }


        private function securityErrorHandler(event:SecurityErrorEvent):void
        {
            trace( "securityErrorHandler: " + event.text );
        }


        private function asyncErrorHandler(event:AsyncErrorEvent):void
        {
            trace( "asyncErrorHandler: " + event.error.message );
        }

    }
}
```

And then use it something like this:

```
var video:Video = new Video();
video.smoothing = false;
if (stage)
{
    video.width  = stage.stageWidth;
    video.height = stage.stageHeight;
}
addChild( video );

loader = new URLLoader();
loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
loader.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, loader_completeHandler, false, 0, true );
loader.addEventListener( IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, loader_ioErrorHandler, false, 0, true );
loader.load( new URLRequest( "URL_OF_VIDEO" ) );


...


function loader_completeHandler( event:Event ):void
{
    var data:ByteArray = ByteArray( loader.data );

    var player:AppendByteVideoLoop = new AppendByteVideoLoop( _video, _data );
    player.play();
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for your answer, this is by far the closest solution I've seen on this topic. This indeed repeats the video without interruptions as advertised. Unfortunately the video playback speed becomes somewhat slower than original. If you play a video 10 times in a row you can see a pretty noticeable slowdown on the overall playing time (I havent measured but it seems visually about 10-20% slower than original). My system is very powerful so I suspect this has something to do with the implementation itself and can be adjusted, as everything should be flying on my machine.

Comment: I haven't checked this code sorry, it's from a project several years ago and was used in a pretty specific environment. Just check you only create the AppendByteVideoLoop once and that NetConnection.Connect.Success is only called once. 

It would benefit from some cleanup code to manage memory usage.